# Sails.js req.files is empty and req.body.image is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I've been trying to understand this since yesterday but I can't find any solutions, even by asking Google and StackOverFlow. 
The problem is that I'm building a project inside which I have "Product" Model, Controller, and Views. On the new.ejs view, I have a form which contains a file tag (named image). So, on the controller, I try to get the image path by logging req.files.image.path in the console but req.files is empty. I also tried to display req.body.image which is undefined.

Here is the client-side code (views/product/new.ejs) :

(This is a Sails.js app)

Here is the client-side code (views/product/new) :

```
<div class='container'>
    <form action='/product/create' role='form' class='form-signin' enctype="multipart/form-data" id='product-form'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label class='sr-only' for='name'>Name of the product</label>
            <input type="text" class='form-control' placeholder="Name" name='name' id='name' />
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label class='sr-only' for='image'>Image of the product</label>
            <input type="file" name='image' id='image' />
        </div>
.
.
.etc...
```

and here is the server-side (api/controllers/ProductController.js) :

```
'create': function(req, res, next) {
    // Include the node file module
    var fs = require('fs');
    console.log(req.files); //This logs : { } in the console
    console.log(req.body.image); //This logs : undefined in the console
    //Readfile with fs doesn't work cause req.files is empty
    // fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function(error, data) {
    //  //get image name
    //  var imageName = req.files.data.name;

    //  //if enable to get name
    //  if (!imageName) {
    //      console.log('error uploading image');
    //      res.redirect('/product/new');
    //      //Else if we have an image
    //  } else {
    //      //change the path to our own
    //      var newPath = __dirname + '/assets/images/products/fullsize/' + imageName;
    //      fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(error) {
    //          console.log(newPath);
    //          //res.redirect('/product' + imageName);
    //      });
    //  }

    // });
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Mat.

Also available here : https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use method=post in your html form

Comment: Thanks I saw that too right after posting this :-). I'll vote for you anyway.